# How can I change a field's widget type on its node edit page?

Tags: media, entities

I have a node type that uses Fuploader image field widget. When a user creates new a node of this type, I want them to be able to use the fuploader widget to upload images. When the user edits that node at some point, I want to switch to the normal imagefield widget. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I do not think, there is simple solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

Login in as super admin:

content management ->content types -> edit [your content type]->managefields

click on configure of that field and there you will see second button which named "Change basic Information"

Click on this button and will get the way to edit widget type.

Comment: I'm looking to switch between widgets. I wan't the user to be able to use the fupload on when adding a new node, but when they edit that node, I don't want the fupload widget to be activated, I only want the standard imagefield widget available.

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at here.  Are you trying to NOT allow a user to upload a second or different image once the first one is uploaded?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest creating two different content types. One would be shown when the user creates something new, and the other when they want to edit. They could share most of the data using the Add Existing Field option, but I think you might need to run Rules after the new content is created, to create a duplicate node of the other content type, using the same information.